# How to call an external application if using exec() defines it as invalid Win32 application in Java?

Tags: java, url, exe

I'm fiddling with opening external applications from Java source code. I am trying to open a launcher for a game called Runescape, which is found inside `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Jagex`. The name of the file inside this directory is `RuneScape Launcher.url`.

This is the code which demonstrates my progress so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //doesn't work
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Jagex\\RuneScape Launcher.url");

   //if Chrome was to be opened, it works, since it is .exe
   // Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println(p.exitValue());
}
```

The error that gets thrown is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Obviously, `RuneScape Launcher.url` is not a valid Win32 application. How to start such an application?

**My research:**
  - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637203/why-does-createprocess-give-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-app) suggests using ShellExecute, however it is written in another programming language. I couldn't find a similar solution for Java.
  - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters) talks about passing parameters when calling an external application, but that external application is .exe
  - [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calling-external-program-java-using-process-runtime/) demonstrates calling external applications, but again only .exe

Then, I've tried starting this launcher from cmd manually ... successfully. First, I've located launcher directory: `cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Jagex` and then called the launcher: `"RuneScape Launcher.url"`. This started the launcher correctly. Why doesn't it start from Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the launcher as an argument to `cmd.exe`:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Jagex\\RuneScape Launcher.url");
```